# Can I use my running shoes' seventh eyelets to fix heel slipping?

Tags: running, running-shoes, shoes

I recently bought a new pair of running shoes. With this pair, I've noticed that my heel slips up and down ever so slightly as I run in them. I've found a few different pages online that mention ways of fixing this by lacing the shoes differently, but none of these pages seem to mention the low seventh eyelets that my shoes have.

Here's what they look like:

[image: My shoe]

As you can see, the first six eyelets (which all have laces through them) are all in a line, but the seventh (which is empty) is lower than the sixth. Can I use this seventh eyelet somehow to keep my heel from slipping as it does?

Answer (score 10):

You can... But in my experience, it's better to use that 7th eyelet slightly differently to prevent heel slipping. It is shown in this video starting around 1:47:

[To the video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?feature=player_detailpage&v=y0BSXa8vE10#t=95s)

Steps (images from [Health on the Run](http://www.healthontherun.net/running/how-to-tie-your-shoes-and-other-shoe-tricks/)):

- Create a loop using the last two eyelets.

  [image]
- Put the shoelace through the hole on the opposite side. Put on the shoe and pull the laces tight

  [image]
- Now you can tie your shoes like normal

  [image]

Comment: Can you provide diagrams or description in addition to the video link?

Comment: It looks to me like the technique consists simply of lacing through the seventh eyelet normally and tying normally.

Comment: Sorry, starting around 1:47.